# is it possible to upgrade built-in Wireless adapter from N to AC

Tags: wireless-networking

I have Lenovo g580 laptop, which comes with (built-in) a/b/g/n Wireless adapter, can I upgrade it with a more recent a/b/g/n/ac one?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - there's actually a really specific [list found here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/G580-list-of-supported-wifi-cards-adaptors/td-p/3380077) for your laptop. It's also really easy to replace a wireless card - if by "upgrade" you meant "replace", which will be your only real option unless you want to buy a wireless dongle of some sort to supplement your current one.

You can [consult your laptop's manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g480_g485_g580_g585_g780_hmm_v1.0_english.pdf) for instructions on accessing/removing the PCI Express Mini Card wireless adapter - page 47.

Comment: Some of these laptops **do not** have hybrid 2.4/5ghz antenna's. To fully support 802.11ac, you may have to replace the antennas. Which of course as we all know is a pain in the @#$&!

Comment: you mean you don't like removing literally everything in a laptop to replace a part?